# Select the first element before by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in selecting the first element before another one that is not in the same tag

Example:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div>
    <form>
        <input />
    </form>

    <div>
        ...
        <div class="thisone"></div>
    </div>
```

Whatever is the HTML Structure of the page i would like to select the first input before the div with the class "thisone"

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
var firstInput = $(".thisone").parent().prevAll().find("input:eq(0)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
alert($('.thisone').parentsUntil('form').parents().find('input').val());
```